# AngularJS: Passing data from a transclude directive to the isolated scope of a sub-directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Based on this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GufJjrn3OxYVSf2oLD5n?p=preview

I have two directives, for the sake of simplicity, let's name them `directiveBlue` and `directiveRed`.

`directiveRed` has to be a sub element of `directiveBlue`.

The `MainCtrl` of our mini app has a simple array under the variable `$scope.elements`.

This variable is passed to the isolate scope that `directiveBlue` creates via the `data-elements` attribute. Notice that the `directiveBlue` has to be a transclude directive.

Then my main problem is, how do I pass the array of elements to the `directiveRed` without having to get it doing it via `$scope.$parent.elements` which seems to me, is a bad practice and then it makes the code tightly coupled.

Any changes to the elements in the deepest directive should then be synched with the rest of the scopes.

Is there any good practice or valid solution for this?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

To be more concrete on my use case:

I've created a plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/i2Busz6E8ehlkG3uEllh?p=preview) with a more concrete situation, where I want to have directive for an action group, I've implemented an option as a simple directive and I want to place my logic in the directives controllers. The method selectAll is pretty simple, but I can imagine having more complex actions which would require the elements from the top scope.

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty of solutions, but without knowing what your goal is, it is more or less guessing. 
The following quote is from the angular docs for [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) and describes the use of `controller`

> (...)The controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase and it is shared with other directives (see require attribute). This allows the directives to communicate with each other and augment each other's behavior. The controller is injectable(...)

a fork of your [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1K1UlbnP5ftgeRwBfGN1?p=preview) to show how to access `MainCtrl`'s `$scope.elements` in `directiveBlue` and `directiveRed`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've created a plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/i2Busz6E8ehlkG3uEllh?p=preview) with a more concrete situation, where I want to have directive for an action group, I've implemented an option as a simple directive and I want to place my logic in the directives controllers. The method selectAll is pretty simple, but I can imagine having more complex actions which would require the elements from the top scope.